# Linux tool to create static binaries from dynamic apps

Tags: linux, static, static-linking

A while back I remember using a tool (similar to `upx`) that would bundle a dynamically linked binary with all of it's various .so dependencies, along with a simple pre-launcher to intercept `dlopen` type calls, all into a single binary executable (great for transferring an application to a remote system where you couldn't guarantee dependencies, frequently done with scheduling/queueing systems in HPC environments).

Can someone help me find this program again?

Comment: I found the original one, "Statifier" - http://statifier.sourceforge.net/ , but I'm interested if anyone knows of anything else like it.

Answer (score 0):

[CDE](http://www.pgbovine.net/cde.html) (Code, Data, and Environment) is a tool that Automatically create portable Linux applications.

Git repo: https://github.com/pgbovine/CDE